# How to use Dom libray in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom, libraries

Good day all. I ´ve been trying to read an xml file in python with the following library: xml.dom.minidom and for some reason the debugger tells me that dom is unrecognized. Do you know what should I do in order to use this library or better than that to read a complete xml file with several children into python?

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show us what you have tried by providing a [mcve]. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Links:

[Data for test_data.xml](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

[Reference on how to use xml.dom.minidom](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/parsing-xml-with-dom-apis-in-python)

You can extract xml data from an xml file using the `parse(filename_or_file, parser=None, bufsize=None)` function in  `xml.dom.minidom`

Contents of `test_data.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Code:

```py
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
tree = parse('test_data.xml').documentElement
countries = tree.getElementsByTagName('country')
for country in countries:
    print(f"Country name: {country.getAttribute('name')}")
    rank = country.getElementsByTagName('rank')[0].childNodes[0].data
    neighbors = []
    for neighbor in country.getElementsByTagName('neighbor'):
        neighbors.append(dict(name=neighbor.getAttribute('name'), direction=neighbor.getAttribute('direction')))
    print(f"Country rank: {rank}")
    print(f"Neighbors: {neighbors}")
    print()
```

Output:

```
Country name: Liechtenstein
Country rank: 1
Neighbors: [{'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E'}, {'name': 'Switzerland', 'direction': 'W'}]

Country name: Singapore
Country rank: 4
Neighbors: [{'name': 'Malaysia', 'direction': 'N'}]

Country name: Panama
Country rank: 68
Neighbors: [{'name': 'Costa Rica', 'direction': 'W'}, {'name': 'Colombia', 'direction': 'E'}]
```

I would prefer to use `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse an xml file as I've found it quite easier than using `xml.dom.minidom`

[Reference on how to use `xml.etree.Elementree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

Comment: Thank you ! one doubt remains, python is not allowing me to use dom, the compiler does not recognize it, what can I do?

Comment: Can you share how you have initialised the dom?

Comment: from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

def main():

     doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse("sample.xml")
     print(doc)
     #print(doc.firstChild.tagName)

Comment: As you've imported the parse function directly, use `parse('sample.xml')` instead of `xml.dom.minidom.parse('sample.xml)`

Comment: `xml.dom.minidom.parse('sample.xml')` will work when your import statement is `import xml`

Comment: it tells me that does not recognizes xml.dom

Comment: @SarkisF: Please **edit your question** to explain the problem. Avoid long discussions in comments to an answer.